# TinyMCE, JQuery capture HTML for output

Tags: jquery, html, image, tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE to format html that can then be previewed and displayed on the same webpage. I then need to cature this html to convert the output to a JPG/PNG image.

I have got as far as configuring tinyMCE and displaying the "content" via a form submission. But I m failing to then capture this. The webpage is

```js
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    height : 500,
    removed_menuitems: 'undo, redo'
});

$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#get-data-form").submit(function(e){

  var content = tinymce.get("texteditor").getContent();

  $("#data-container").html(content);
        

  return false;

 });

});
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding:0;
    margin:80px;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
table td {
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
textarea {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
h1 {
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
} 
.posterPrev {
    width:324px;
    height:486px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin:20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header {
    height:36px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
.footer {
    height:54px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
#data-content {
    height:486px;
    background-color: #999999;
    margin:0;
    padding:100 40 20 40;
    display:block;
}
#data-container {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TinyMCE - Setup</title>
        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getdata.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formatting.css">
        
 </head>
 <body>
  
<table class="prevFrame">
<tr><td >       
        <form id="get-data-form" method="post">

   <textarea class="tinymce" id="texteditor"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Preview">

  </form>
</td>  
<td>    
  
        <div id="poster-div" class="posterPrev">
            <div class="header">header</div>
            <div id="data-content">
                <div id="data-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">footer</div>
        </div>

</td></tr>
</table>
       
        
 </body>
</html>
```

The webpage looks like this
[Test Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2bo9.png)

Which works OK. But I don't seem to be able to capture the content from TinyMCE when it is displayed in a div container. I would like to capture the DIV containers to create "static" head and foot along with the content from tinyMCE - any suggestions. The end result is to send the captured HTML to convert this to a JPG/PNG.The image is to be used on a basic display system that doesn't allow for text formatting but can display an image.